# How do you get the TouchView nuget working with Android in Xamarin.Android project?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, effects

I'm trying to use the nuget package TouchView.  I have it working in an iOS project, but I cannot get the same functionality to work with Android.  The sample application from https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/TouchEffect works, but a new project does not.

I've added the TouchView 4.1.3 nuget to my Xamarin (.net standard) project as well as to the Android project.

In MainActivity.cs, here is my OnCreate:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        TouchEffectPreserver.Preserve();
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

In the shared project, here is my MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:touch="clr-namespace:TouchEffect;assembly=TouchEffect"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             x:Class="TouchExample.MainPage"
             Title="TouchExample">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Frame 
            BorderColor="#56bad3"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HasShadow="false" 
            BackgroundColor="White" 
            CornerRadius="40" 
            HeightRequest="80" 
            WidthRequest="80" 
            Padding="0,0,0,0" 
            Margin="0,100,0,0"
            touch:TouchEff.RegularBackgroundColor="White"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedBackgroundColor="#56bad3"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedScale="1"
            touch:TouchEff.RippleCount="1"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedTranslationX="5"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedTranslationY="5"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedAnimationDuration="500"
            touch:TouchEff.RegularAnimationDuration="500">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding KeyCommand}" CommandParameter="1" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <Frame.Effects>
                <touch:TouchEff Completed="TouchEff_Completed"/>
            </Frame.Effects>
            <Grid Padding="0,0,0,15" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="1" FontSize="30" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>

        <Frame 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HasShadow="false" 
            BackgroundColor="#56bad3"
            CornerRadius="40" 
            HeightRequest="80" 
            WidthRequest="80" 
            Padding="0,0,0,0" 
            Margin="0,100,0,0"
            touch:TouchEff.RegularBackgroundColor="#56bad3"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedBackgroundColor="LightBlue"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedScale="1"
            touch:TouchEff.RippleCount="1"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedTranslationX="5"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedTranslationY="5"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedAnimationDuration="500"
            touch:TouchEff.RegularAnimationDuration="500">
            <Frame.Effects>
                <touch:TouchEff Completed="TouchEff_Completed"/>
            </Frame.Effects>
            <Label Text="# Pad" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="30"/>
        </Frame>

        <Frame 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HasShadow="false" 
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            CornerRadius="40" 
            HeightRequest="80" 
            WidthRequest="80" 
            Padding="0,0,0,0" 
            Margin="0,100,0,0"
            touch:TouchEff.RegularBackgroundColor="Red"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedBackgroundColor="DarkRed"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedScale="1"
            touch:TouchEff.RippleCount="1"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedTranslationX="5"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedTranslationY="5"
            touch:TouchEff.PressedAnimationDuration="500"
            touch:TouchEff.RegularAnimationDuration="500">
            <Frame.Effects>
                <touch:TouchEff Completed="TouchEff_Completed"/>
            </Frame.Effects>
            <Label Text="Hangup" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="30"/>
        </Frame>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And the code behind MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TouchExample
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TouchEff_Completed(VisualElement sender, TouchEffect.EventArgs.TouchCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("We got here!");
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, that is all that I should need to do for the effects to work, but they don't.  What am I missing?

For iOS, I did the same thing, except updating AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching() instead of MainActivity.OnCreate()  The iOS example project is working.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a Xamarin Forms bug.  The library works on Android using a minimum Xamarin Forms version of 4.1.0.555618.

No other code changes are necessary.